# Changing edit text style in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I would like to style my edit text field like the following in the easiet way.

There seems to be multiple methods of doing it (that includes styling the theme). I just want to get it done whatever the method is.

Can someone please point me to the right direction?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take 2 approaches to this subject.

1. Programatically draw that shape, since you asked for a simpler answer and I find this approach more dificult I won't get into it, but you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849729/drawing-background-shape-with-one-corner-and-two-cutting-edges-android) an example.
2. Is using [9patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html). You fill find more info on the link provided but for now lets just say that 9patch is an image you want to use. For this example I created this 9patch image (it is just a test image to show you how it works):

[image: test 9patch]

You paste that image into your drawable folder, and if the image is called test.9.png you create an EditText like this:

```
   <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et"        
        android:background="@drawable/test"/>
```

And the result will look like this:
[image]

Now, of course you need to create a proper image, with transparent background and better drawn (this was done in paint) but I hope it will be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, Will give this a go